# MS Vc++ 2017 takes too long to produce output

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, g++, c++14

It's a simple Union-Find Program. The Problem is when I ran the code on Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, it gives no output although G++ does.

The Code is : [Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/TMchC7)

Code :

```
`// UnionFind.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
 //
 //#include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <algorithm>

  using namespace std;

  #define ul unsigned long long int

  int root(int child, vector<int> &A) {
      while (A[child] != child) {
          A[child] = A[A[child]];
          child = A[child];
      }
      return child;
  }


  void weighted_union(int child, int parent, vector<int> &size, vector<int> &A) {

      int root_child = root(child, A);
      int root_parent = root(parent, A);

      if (size[root_child] < size[root_parent]) {
          A[root_child] = A[root_parent];
          size[root_parent] += size[root_child];
      } 
      else
      {
          A[root_parent] = A[root_child];
          size[root_child] += size[root_parent];
      }

  }

  void print(vector<int> &T) {

      for (auto i : T) {
          cout << i << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
  }

  void func(ul t, vector<int> &A, vector<int> &size) {
      ul x = t, y = t;
      int in1 = 0, in2 = 0;

      while (x > 0) {
          y = x >> 1;
          in2 = in1 + 1;
          while (y > 0) {
              if ((x & 1) && (y & 1)) {
                  weighted_union(in1, in2, size, A);
              }
              in2++;
              y = y >> 1;
          }
          in1++;
          x = x >> 1;
      }
  }




  int connected(vector<int> &A) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
          if (A[i] == i) {
              count++;
          }
      }

      return count;
  }

  int main()
  {
      int n;
      cin >> n;

      vector<ul> T(n);
      vector< vector<int> > A(n, vector<int>(64));
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
              A[i][j] = j;
          }
      }

      vector<int> size(64, 1);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          cin >> T[i];
          func(T[i], A[i], size);
              for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
                  size[j] = 1;
              }
      }

      int count = 0;
      count += 64;
      unsigned long long int donot = 0;

      int j = 0;
      unsigned long long int a;
      vector<int> temp(64);

      for (unsigned long long int i = 1; i < (1 << n); i++) {
          if (i == (1 << donot)) {
              count += connected(A[donot]);
              donot++;
              continue;
          }

          j = 0;
          a = i;

          for (int t = 0; t < 64; t++) {
              temp[t] = t;
          }

          while (a > 0) {
              if ((a & (ul)1) == 1)
              {
                  for (int ii = 0; ii < 64; ii++) {
                      temp[ii] = min(A[j][ii], temp[ii]);
                  }
              }
              a >>= (ul)1;
              j++;
          }

          count += connected(temp);
      }

      cout << count;

      return 0;
  }`
```

*plz note the program is for an online competition problem*

It compiles successfully but for input such as

```
20 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615 18446744073709551615
```

Well it is a bit too long but MS Vc++ produces no output even after few minutes of waiting although ideone/or G++ compiler does it in 0.62s.

For smaller inputs such as

```
    3 2 5 9
```

it gives correct output and fast.

For simple programs such as this MS Vc++ and G++ should not affect output.

Am I missing something in the code that prevents msvc++ from giving the output?

System specs : Core i3 5005U @ 2Ghz (2 Core (4 Logical)
               / 4 GB Ram / Window 10 (64-bit)
               no other task running while executing the program

Comment: included the code

Comment: In Visual Studio are you set to produce a debug or release build?

Comment: debug build (x86)

Comment: That's probably it then. Debug builds are un/barely optimized and slow as molasses to make the program easier to debug.

Comment: well release (x64) gives the output. Thanks